# reload not working in ionic app

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building my app in ionic framework and my login code initially was

```
AuthService.login(data.username, data.password).then(function(authenticated) {
  $state.go('app.dashboard', {}, {reload: true});
}, function(err) {
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Login failed!',
    template: 'Please check your credentials!'
  });
});
```

But unlike what I expected, page didnt reload after login and still showed back button with no menu option. I now changed the code to

```
AuthService.login(data.username, data.password).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  $state.go('app.dashboard').then(function() {
    $window.location.reload(true);
  });

}, function (err) {
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Login failed!',
    template: 'Please check your credentials!'
  });
});
```

Code I now have works well on some of the android mobiles but wont work well on some android mobiles(4.x versions).

What is the right way to reload after login?

I think its behaviour of html. following is my menu.html code

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="right">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
            <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
            <!-- content -->
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Following is my app.js code

```
$stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.profile', {
    url: "/profile",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/profile.html"
      }
    }
  })
//more pages
;
```

Comment: Why do you need to reload in the first place?

Comment: If I dont reload app doesnt have menu button, and has back button. Clicking on back button takes me back to login page! http://imgur.com/zonlBQc

Comment: Change display logic and reject loading of login path if user already logged in

Comment: Reloading is not the right way to show menu button. You need to check your routes.

Comment: But if you want to go this way then try    $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); on dashboard start. It will refresh view instead of whole page.

Comment: I added html code also. I think it depends on html! I tried $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); but even with that I dont see menu icon.

Comment: I want to see menu item in Dashboard but appears only when I do hard reload! Which doesn't work on some android versions

Answer (score 1):

to make sure a page reloads every time you enter it use a

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){
 //place anything you want to run evertime this view is entered here. for example
 //$scope.getData();
 //$scope.variable1 = something;
})
```

this will run everything you put inside it before the view is entered. Here is a example of how I use it.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
            $scope.doRefresh();
        });
```

and in my doRefresh function:

I grab a bunch of data I need to refresh :

```
$scope.doRefresh = function () {
        $scope.setRoles();
        $scope.payHistory();
        $scope.LoadBoard();
        $scope.Blog();
        $scope.getHOS();
        $scope.getFuelData();
    }
};
```

You can check all your logic on refresh and set variables using ng-if or ng-show to display the correct buttons in the menu bar.
look here for more ionicView events: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Answer (score 0):

I had my login view also as one of the other views of menutabs. I made it a normal view by changing my uirouter code to

```
  .state('login', {
    url: "/public",
    templateUrl:'templates/public.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
```

from

```
  .state('app.login', {
    url: "/dashboard/login",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

and it solved the problem. I no longer need to reload.